# How to make subdomain and muti-site but wordpress isn't in root?

Tags: multisite

my wordpress isn't in root but it is in public_html/home and then I would like make multi-site and subdomain.

example when I create subdomain name "foo.domain.com" foo directory is created in public_html which path is public_html/foo. but when I make multi-site in wordpress which Site Address will be started www.domain.com/home and when I enter foo name. I just get path is www.domain.com/home/foo

Can I make subdomain and mutisite that they aren't in root webpath?

Answer (score 1):

WordPress [must be installed in the root of your domain](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network#Types_of_multisite_network) in order to set up subdomain-based multisite.

However, you can [move WordPress to the root](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_Within_Your_Site).